# Magento WYSOWYG "Insert Image" Displays Blank Page After URL Update

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I have a issue with magento 1.9.2.2. Today we updated the "base URL" to display the "www" part of our url at the store in addition to updating the haccess file to. Orginally it was just https://domainname.com. Now we have setup to display like this: https://www.domainname.com. Since then there are some icons that wont display throughout the backend and the today I tried adding a new image to the static block section and I only get a blank page when I go to insert a image into the editor. In addition to this I uploaded to free imaging hosting site and inserted the url directly and it reverts back. I dont think something updated all the way but not sure what it could be. Anyone experience this issue?

Comment: View any errors in browser console ?

Comment: Have you done the usual initial trio: cleared image cache, reindexed everything and cleared all caches? Also, as you mentioned icons, how are the images referenced in your CSS file - if those are specified there.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was incorrect to redirect non www traffic to www domain via htaccess file in magento. The proper way of doing this is from the web tab in the backend. I had changed it in the web tab but also updated the htaccess file which I believe created some sort of conflict. I have since removed the update from the htaccess file and updated only the admin portal base urls. Thanks everyone